# WEIRD problem inserting in database using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

Basically, I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC project using Entity Framework, I have downloaded template, and there is a Contact session, I have created model, base class etc...

But the problem is that I cannot insert into database:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "php-email-form" }))
{
```

If I remove the `@class` attribute, data insertion works fine, but the page style is ruined. The class `php-email-form` is only for styling purposes.

If I leave using like this, it works, I can insert data, but the style of the page is ruined

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Contact", FormMethod.Post))
{
```

The code of form

[image]

I tried:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Create", "Contact")" method="post" class="php-email-form">
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<!-- Your form elements go here -->
</form>
```

Still the same, only if I remove class I can input, but style is ruined

Comment: There might be some javascript handlers attached to your php-email-form class.

Comment: Have you attached a debugger and set a breakpoint in your `Contact` controller `Create` method? What's the difference between the post data with and without the `php-email-form` class?

Comment: Hey guys, I fixed the issue.
The problem was that some javascript handlers were attached to myphp-email-form class. I delete the file , and now I can submit.

Thanks a lot for helping me,
Best of luck.